# Echo name of value in related table in view

Tags: laravel

Please note: I am pretty new to laravel and programming in general.

So I have a many to many relationship between 'user' and 'role' and use this new thing I just learned a pivot table 'role_user'. Now I want to show a list of my users and the name of the role that they have.

**users migration**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**roles migration**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

**role_user migration**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateRoleUserTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
    }
}
```

**User model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'roles_id'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function authorizeRoles($roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            return $this->hasAnyRole($roles) || 
                    abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
        }
        return $this->hasRole($roles) || 
                abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
    }
    /**
    * Check multiple roles
    * @param array $roles
    */
    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
        return null !== $this->roles()->whereIn(‘name’, $roles)->first();
    }
    /**
    * Check one role
    * @param string $role
    */
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return null !== $this->roles()->where(‘name’, $role)->first();
    }
}
```

**Role model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

**My view**

```
@extends('layouts/app')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4>Users</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (count($users) > 0)
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Created on</th>
                                <th>Role</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    @foreach ($users as $user)
                        <tr>
                                <td><em>{{$user->name}}</em></td>
                                <td><em>{{$user->email }} </em></td>
                                <td><em>{{$user->created_at}}</em></td>
                                <td><em>{{$user->roles->name}} </em></td> 
                                <td>
                                    <span class="table-remove">
                                         {!!Form::open(['action' =>['userController@destroy', $user->id], 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
                                            {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
                                            {{ Form::button('<i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm', 'type' => 'submit']) }}
                                        {!!Form::close()!!}
                                    </span>
                                </td>                                
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@else
    <p>No users found</p>

@endif
```

**UserController**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('users.index',['users'=> $users]);
    }
}
```

Right now I get the error:

Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\AmbitieProject\resources\views\users\index.blade.php)

I try to echo '$user->roles->name' which I believe should work in a one to many relationship but I am not sure how I can echo the name of the role using a many to many relationship

Comment: Can you share your controller?

Comment: `$user->roles` will return a collection of one or more roles associated with the user. You need to then get each role in a loop, or if there is only one use `$user->roles->first()->name` to grab the first entry in the collection: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-first

Comment: $user->roles->first()->name works thanks!

Comment: I added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pivot table will return a Laravel [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections). As such, you cannot access the property of a record without first getting the record.

If there are many roles that are possible, which I assume to be true since you went the pivot table route, you should do something like this to list them as a comma separated list:

```php
<td>
    <em>
        @if ($user->roles->count() > 0)
            {{ $user->roles->implode('name', ',') }}
        @endif
    </em>
</td>
```

If there is only one role possible, then just use `first()` to get the first record:

```php
<td>
    <em>
        @if ($user->roles->count() > 0)
            {{$user->roles->first()->name}} 
        @endif
    </em>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have taken a mistake to define a relationship.

Please define the `pivot` table in the relationship.

**Role model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'role_users'); //plural name
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks. It did not solve my issue though.